# getting most repeated value fromo sql table fields

Tags: php, sql

I want to get most one repeated value in sql table column field below is my sql structure.

I want to get most repeated value from Topic field

Table name is `Orange` and field name with values is `topic`

```
topic
 1
 2
 1
 3
 1
 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT    count(topic) 
FROM      Orange  
GROUP BY  topic
ORDER BY  count(topic) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

`select topic, count(topic) from orange group by topic order by count(topic) desc;`

That is the SQL query to run btw.

Comment: in my example the most repeated value is 1 in topic field i want get result with sql query

Comment: @ZohaibBaig I edited the query to give you the topic number as well as the count. That is the query to run btw.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for here is the Modal average - check this link that has an example of Modal operations in Sql Server and adapt as required.

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/calculating-mean-median-and-mode-with-sq

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(COUNT(`topic`)) FROM `Orange`;
```

Comment: That won't work, you cannot nest aggregates like that (although I admit it would sometimes be quite handy)

Comment: then you could solve it with a subquery, though that can be nasty. Somethign like this would solve the question then SELECT MAX(`x`.`counted`) FROM (SELECT COUNT(`topic`) AS `counted` FROM `Orange`) AS `x`;